# Error to save BCryptPasswordEncoder in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the folowing code to gerenate a password encrypted and save in the database:

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashPassword = passwordEncoder.encode("admin");
```

I get the result and save in database but when i try to get in my `UserDetailsService` i am having the follow problems:

If I try to pass for user details the password directly i have the follow message:

```
return new User(user.getEmail(),user.getPassword(), getPermissions(user));
```

**There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”**

If I put a passwordEncoder as the following:

```
 @Autowired
 private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
 //add the passwordEnconder
 return new User(user.getEmail(), passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()), getPermissions(user));
```

I have the following problem:

**Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: error="invalid_grant", error_description="Bad credentials"**

But if get the passwordEnconder and put in the user with password directly as bellow I have success:

```
//success code
return new User(user.getEmail(),passwordEncoder.encode("admin"), getPermissions(user));
```

So how can I generate a valid password for save in database?

My method with the success code is:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> userOptional = repository.findByEmail(email);
    User user = userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuário e/ou senha incorretos"));
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),passwordEncoder.encode("admin"), getPermissions(user));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved adding `{bcrypt}` before the password generated.

Example:

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
System.out.println("{bcrypt}" + passwordEncoder.encode("admin"));
```

I get the result and save in database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a bean for **BCryptPasswordEncoder** in a configuration file.

```
  @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Autowired encoder wherever you need to encode password.

```
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder encoder;
```

Encode password before save as below.
You use

```
String password = encoder.encode("Test"));
DB.save(password);
```

Comment: I already had the problem was generate the password in a main method for example, thanks.

Comment: You should do it by CommandLinerRunner rather than main method

Comment: Creating object each time is not good practice. We should use spring dependencies injection using autowired

Comment: Happy to help :)